# The bottom of the printed objects has waves after replacing the nozzle

Tags: print-quality, nozzle

I had a problem with my nozzle on my homemade printer. The problem was that the nozzle with a 0.4 mm diameter wasn't putting out any plastic. I replaced the nozzle with a 0.2 mm one and now the bottom of my model is looking like this: [image: waves]
I tried to change flow,temperatures and speed.
But nothing helped it keeps making this waves. At the old 0.4 mm nozzle there everything was okay.

Comment: You need to solve the problem (lack of extrusion from nozzle) rather than randomly switching to a different diameter.  Since you're getting output from a smaller nozzle, clearly the 0.4 mm one is clogged.

Comment: @CarlWitthoft - no need to be so harsh! :)  it may be that he did not manage to unclog it and only had a 0.2 mm readily available...

Comment: @CarlWitthoft Why I should stay at the stock nozzle diameter if I want to get different printing quality? That's not what you call randomly

Comment: @Coder_fox because you asked a specific question and implied that you were trying to figure out why your 0.4 mm nozzle wasn't working.   My point is that you should find the root cause or there'll just be more trouble down the road.

Comment: This is a flow issue between speed and temperature, the temperature seems to be too high.

Comment: Replacing your nozzle will allow for more flow. This means that your extruder is now able to push out more filament on the same extrusion multiplier. Slowing down the first layer and turning down the extrusion multiplier with steps of 0.05 will most certainly help fix this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, there are a few potential issues here:
1: your belts are not tight enough. This will cause your bed to shake during printing, giving you wavy first layers.

2: your filament is bad. If you have an inconsistent filament diameter, thus can lead to inconsistent extrusion rates, and cause a wavy appearance.

3: your nozzle is jammed. The nozzle you bought may have something stuck inside of it, leading to underextrusion, which, in some cases, can lead to a wavy appearance.

Comment: If the belts are not tight enough than will speed decreasement help?

Comment: Sure, decreasing the speed would help, but the best solution is to retighten the belts.

Answer (score 2):

Without more detail is difficult to say with certainty what the *root* cause of the problem is, but it looks like **too much material is being deposited on the bed**.

A few things to try/check:

- **Make sure the nozzle is not leaking**.  If it is, you should see fused plastic coming out from the seal nozzle/hot-end and/or hot-end/heat break and trickling down.  This is often the case when the nozzle hasn't been tightened enough, or it has been changed with the hot-end being cold, or if the internal PTFE tube has been dislodged upwards (does not apply to all-metal hot-ends).
- **Make sure you changed the appropriate setting for the nozzle diameter**.  This is *not* "flow" it is a separate setting.  If you haven't, your printer is now extruding ~4 times as much filament as it ought.
- **Recalibrate your nozzle height**.  This should be done at each nozzle change, as each nozzle is slightly different from the other, and it is possible your new nozzle now sits too close to the bed.

**EDIT**: also, the picture is too low-res to be sure, but looking at the skirt, **it looks like the extruded plastic comes out in blobs**.  If it is not due to leakage, then I would suggest to also check that the filament is not slipping through the gears of the extruder.  If you have access to a suitable thermometer, you could also check that the hot-end temperature is stable at the level it should.

Final thought: have you ever succeeded printing with that filament spool?  It is unlikely, but it may be for example a defective one, or a mis-labelled one (so your printing temperature may be wrong).

Comment: 1. The nozzle is not leaking. 2. I changed the nozzle diameter in the slicing software 3. I recalibrated the bed. I have done this when I installed the new nozzle so that's not the problem.

Comment: @Coder_fox - Maybe obvious question, but... have you also re-calibrated your extruder (https://www.matterhackers.com/articles/how-to-calibrate-your-extruder) in the process?

Comment: Yes I recalibrated it a few times.

Comment: @Coder_fox - see my edits.  Just additional ideas, I may be off-track

Comment: The filament is not slipping and the temperature is ok.And yes I did succeeded with this filament spool all the times with the 0.4mm nozzle. Also I changed the level hight to 0.1mm and now it looks much better. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

The layer thickness should not be more that 75% of your nozzle diameter: [Wavy lines on 1st layer only](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/questions/11679/wavy-lines-on-1st-layer-only)